# How to create an update query with typeorm and Oracle json column?

Tags: oracle, typeorm

I have an Oracle table with a JSON column that I want to update, and I am using TypeORM with javascript. I need to access the JSON column in the where clause, following is the raw sql query and what I am attempting with typeORM:

Query updates the date to current date where the key's (inside the json column) value is 123.

```
entityManager.query(`UPDATE TABLE_NAME T
                     SET DATE = CURRENT_DATE
                     WHERE T.JSON_COLUMN.key = '123'`)
```

The query with createQueryBuilder:

```
tableRepository.createQueryBuilder()
                             .update('TABLE_NAME')
                             .set({DATE: '2021-07-23 10:07:10'})
                             .where('JSON_COLUMN.key = :key', {key: '123'})
                             .execute();
```

I am not sure how to access the JSON column's key in the where clause. Ideally, I would use the dot operator in SQL to access the JSON columns key value pairs, like so:
`JSON_Column_Name.key = value` but I cannot find a way to implement it with Oracle.
Any help would be appreciated.